# nginx live adaptive bitrate streaming:- not able to switch quality manuallly?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, live-streaming, nginx-config

I am using Nginx for live adaptive bitrate streaming. My live streaming is working fine.
Also, the chunks are getting created and the master playlist is also getting created as you can see in this image.

### My config

```
        application live {
            live on; # Allows live input

            
            exec_push  /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name
                    -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)" -c:v libx264 -vprofile baseline -vlevel 3.1 -s 640x360  -b:v 1200k  -strict -2   -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 96k  -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/$name_hi
                -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*3)" -c:v libx264 -vprofile baseline -vlevel 3.1 -s 240x360  -b:v 1200k  -strict -2   -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 96k  -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/$name_low;

                
        }
```

**This is my master playlist**
[image]

**This is my each playlist m3u8 file**
[image]

But when I point the master playlist to the videojs (hlsjs) added it is showing the quality

1. auto
2. undefinedp

But when I use some other test stream from online then it is showing me all available quality

**using my live stream generated using nginx ffmpeg**

[image]

**using other live stream**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `RESOLUTION` attribute to your master playlist in the `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` tag. This is optional in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.4.2 but it's required by the quality selector UI plugin.

See: https://github.com/chrisboustead/videojs-hls-quality-selector/issues/8

Nginx RTMP module config example:

```
hls_variant <variant_name> BANDWIDTH=<bandwidth>,RESOLUTION=<resolution>;
```

Comment: how can I add that to the master.m3u8 as that was being created by the nginx and ffmpeg itself.

Comment: I had also updated my question for more understanding

Comment: @AshadNasim assuming you're using `hls_variant` in the nginx RTMP module config then try `hls_variant <var> BANDWIDTH=<bandwidth>,RESOLUTION=<w>x<h>` and replace the values with your actual ones. You might also want to add `CODECS` for good measure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had added that in my Nginx but the problem is it is not switching quality manually

Comment: @AshadNasim check if the master playlist actually contains the new resolution attribute. Did you reload the module configuration?

Comment: how can I add that, as that is getting generated from nginx and ffmpeg

Comment: @AshadNasim reload the module configuration in nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224859/discussion-between-ashad-nasim-and-aergistal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for help